# Twitter Ads API: Unable to retrieve all Promoted Tweets

Tags: twitter, ads-api

We are reading the Promoted Tweets data by pulling [Active Entities](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/analytics/api-reference/active-entities) and then their respective data from [Synchronous Analytics](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/analytics/api-reference/synchronous) endpoint.

Next step is to get [Promoted Tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/campaign-management/api-reference/promoted-tweets) data for same Active Entities from Promoted Tweet Endpoint, So we can have information such as LineItemId. We need LineItemId so we can determine the hierarchy which is present [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/hierarchy-terminology)

**Issue**: But while fetching Promoted Tweets data we can see some of the Entity Ids that are available from Active Entities endpoint are not coming from Promoted Tweets endpoint. We are reading Promoted tweets with `with_deleted=true`.

It would be great if someone can guide us whether it is expected or we are missing something.

Comment: It would help if you can share code and the errors, and what you've tried and what is not working.

Comment: Reading promoted tweets using "/8/accounts/18ce54ie6t4/promoted_tweets?with_deleted=true" url. But around 33 Entity Ids are not coming. But when we read same account id information using Active Entities we can able to fetch data properly for those Ids.

Comment: @AndyPiper I have added my request url in comments.

Comment: There is a known issue where the active entities returns promoted tweets for specific campaign objectives that aren't supported via the API. There is an open bug with the team to filter these out. I'd suggest asking Twitter Ads API (non-programming questions) at twittercommunity.com